# How to detect key using pitch of audio ios app

Tags: ios

Is there any body who can help me in finding the pitch of audio file. I have a code in which pitch is calculating via Mic, but i want to detect a Pitch signal and its Strength?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish? Your question is very broad. Also, where are you getting stuck? You say you have code to calculate these things, so what part do you need help with? Please show the code you've tried that's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you need to use avaudioplayer . it will give you peakpowers for pitch of audio . with these peakpowers are actually signal strength , you can do animation from that.

```
 audioPlayer.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [audioPlayer updateMeters];
if([audioPlayer isMeteringEnabled] ){
    for (int currChannel = 0; currChannel < [audioPlayer numberOfChannels]; currChannel++) {
        //strength of audio channel
        NSLog(@"channel# %d %0.2f %0.2f", currChannel, [audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:currChannel], [audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:currChannel]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this link might also help http://lovingod.host.sk/iphone/developers/avmeter_colon_build_a_vu_meter.html